# Textile - Cell padding

Tags: image, cell, textile

I'm using an external map for my Obsidian Portal campaign (uses Textile), but the map is pieced together with separate smaller images. I would like to keep the format, of separate images that I can click and view a section of map, but cell-padding gets in the way of making the map seamless as it should appear...or its an image properties problem, I'm not sure...

Is there any way to fix this so that the image appears complete, and still functions as links to separate sections of the map? I've included a snippet of the table below as it appears on my portal...

Thanks!

```
| |_. A |_. B |_. C |_. D |
|_. 1 | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog11.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog11.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog12.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog12.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog13.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog13.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog14.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog14.png |
|_. 2 | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog21.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog21.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog22.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog22.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog23.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog23.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog24.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog24.png |
|_. 3 | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog31.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog31.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog32.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog32.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog33.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog33.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog34.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog34.png |
|_. 4 | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog41.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog41.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog42.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog42.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog43.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog43.png | !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog44.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog44.png |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textile itself does not add padding itself, you can remove it with CSS, e.g.:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0 0;
    border: none
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can also assign a class or id to the table and it's elements, have a look at the documentation: https://txstyle.org/doc/15/tables

And you can assign the style manually to all elements:

```
table{padding: 0; margin:0; border-spacing: 0 0;  border-collapse: collapse; border: none}.
| |_{padding: 0; margin:0}. A |_{padding: 0; margin:0}. B |_{padding: 0; margin:0}. C |_{padding: 0; margin:0}. D |
|_{padding: 0; margin:0}. 1 |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog11.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog11.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog12.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog12.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog13.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog13.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog14.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog14.png |
|_{padding: 0; margin:0}. 2 |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog21.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog21.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog22.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog22.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog23.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog23.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog24.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog24.png |
|_{padding: 0; margin:0}. 3 |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog31.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog31.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog32.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog32.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog33.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog33.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog34.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog34.png |
|_{padding: 0; margin:0}. 4 |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog41.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog41.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog42.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog42.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog43.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog43.png |{padding: 0; margin:0}. !http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog44.png!:http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/gaming/dnd/greyhawk/map/nwog44.png |
```